# is it possible to close all the tabs in VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

If I have say for example 20 tabs open in VS 2010.

Is there a shortcut to closing all of them instead of manually click 'X' for each one?

Comment: @DanielA.White How to Ask - "Provide details. Share your research."

Comment: @DanielA.White didn't read the questions before marking it as a duplicate...

Comment: Google doesn't know? Try searching google for your title.

Comment: ok thanks for all the answers guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using ALT + W + L. This would help you to close all the open documents at once.

Please vote if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Window → Close All Documents.

I always bind this to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Right click on one of the tabs, select "Close all but this" the manually close the last one.

Comment: to close all, either right click then select Close All, or ctrl + k + w (for windows)

Answer (score 1):

you can right click on a tab ->Close all but this. This will close all tabs except the one you clicked. Then you can click the "x" for the last tab remaining.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your own keyboard shortcut on Window.CloseAllDocuments action in VS options. By default there is none.